# Can't read Varray/Nested table and custom types in PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, oracle12c, oci8

Each time i try to do a select query for a field with a custom type/nested table like this:

```
create or replace type phone_list_type as VARRAY(3) of varchar(30);
create or replace type Email_list_type as VARRAY(3) of varchar(30);
```

Table Users:

```
create table USERS
(
  USER_ID              INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
  USER_NAME            VARCHAR2(20)         not null,
  USER_PASSWORD        VARCHAR2(200)        not null,
  USER_CREATIONDATE    DATE                 default sysdate,
  USER_EMAIL           Email_list_type,
  USER_PHONE           phone_list_type,
  constraint PK_USERS primary key (USER_ID)
);
```

I get the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: oci_fetch_object(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes:
>   expected CHAR got ARRAY
>
> Filename: oci8/oci8_result.php

Here's My Model, the controller just loads the view with model data.

```
    function users_list_all()
  {
      $this->db->select('USER_ID,USER_NAME,USER_PASSWORD,USER_CREATIONDATE,USER_EMAIL,USER_PHONE');
      $result = $this->db->get('USERS');
      return $result->result();
  }
```

Same with Nested Table, but instead is: expected CHAR got TABLE, even if the type has only 2 varchars like this one:

```
create or replace type coordinates_type as OBJECT(
latitude varchar(20),
longitude varchar(20));
```

I'm using Oracle Database 12c and PHP version 5.6.21 with XAMPP.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] - including your PHP code.